# SAS: Output numeric values rounded to one decimal place unless integer

Tags: formatting, sas, report

I need to take a value like `18.433333333` and output it as `18.4`.  At the same time, I need a value like `5` to be output as `5`.

How can I do this?

All my numbers fall within the range [0, 100).  So, a width of 4 seems appropriate.  Three for each number character and one for the decimal.  The best choices for format appear to be `BESTDw.p` or `w.d`.

If I use `BESTD4.1` then `5` is `5` as desired, but `18.433333333` is `18`.

If I use `4.1` then `18.433333333` is `18.4` as desired, but `5` is `5.00`.

This appears in the context of PROC REPORT.

```
data example;
  input 
    ID $ 
    wd 
    bestdwp
    ;

  datalines;
  1 18.433333333 18.433333333
  2 5 5
  ;
run;

proc report data = example;
  column  
    ID
    wd
    bestdwp
    ;

  define ID      / 'ID';
  define wd      / 'w.d'       format = 4.1;
  define bestdwp / 'BESTDw.p'  format = bestd4.1;
run;
```

The output is then:

```
                                           BEST
                           ID         w.d  Dw.p
                           1         18.4    18
                           2          5.0     5
```

Comment: Best4.1 works in SAS 9.4. The docs seem confusing regarding this though and I would expect that bestD4.1 should have worked as well. My answers are being deleted so I posted it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BEST4.1` instead of `BESTD4.1`

From the documentation

> Integers are written without decimals.
>
> Numbers with decimals are written with as many digits to the left and right of the decimal point as needed or as allowed by the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a custom picture format. I'm not sure whether there is a simpler way, other than converting your numeric variable to text before passing it to `proc report`:

```
proc format;
picture mixed
  %macro loop;
    %do i = 0 %to 99;
      &i = '99'
      &i <-< %eval(&i+1) = '99.9'
    %end;
  %mend;
  %loop;
run;

data _null_;
  do i = 18.33, 18;
    put i mixed.;
  end;
run;
```

Output:

```
18.3
  18
```

A similarly constructed non-picture format also works:

```
proc format;
value mixed
  %macro loop;
    %do i = 0 %to 99;
      &i = [2.]
      &i <-< %eval(&i+1) = [4.1]
    %end;
  %mend;
  %loop;
run;
```